# python dataframe to_dict by index, exclude NaN

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, nan

samp dataframe

```
     v1 v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
index                                                                   
0   -2  -2  -2  NaN -2  -2
1   -2  -2  -2  NaN -2  -2
2   -2  -2  -2  NaN -2  -2
3   -2  -2  -2  -2  -2  -2
4   -2  -2  -2  NaN -2  -2
```

Am trying to change dataframe to dictionary
and i want to ignore 'nan' field in json documents

What am trying:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame((samp.to_dict('index')).items())
```

Desired output:

```
index    values
0   {'v1':'-2', 'v2':'-2','v3':'-2','v5':'-2','v6':'-2'}
1   {'v1':'-2', 'v2':'-2','v3':'-2','v5':'-2','v6':'-2'}
2   {'v1':'-2', 'v2':'-2','v3':'-2','v5':'-2','v6':'-2'}
3   {'v1':'-2', 'v2':'-2','v3':'-2','v4':'-2','v5':'-2','v6':'-2'}
4   {'v1':'-2', 'v2':'-2','v3':'-2','v5':'-2','v6':'-2'}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it with `apply`

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().to_dict(),axis=1)
Out[362]: 
index
0    {'v3': -2.0, 'v5': -2.0, 'v6': -2.0, 'v1': -2....
1    {'v3': -2.0, 'v5': -2.0, 'v6': -2.0, 'v1': -2....
2    {'v3': -2.0, 'v5': -2.0, 'v6': -2.0, 'v1': -2....
3    {'v4': -2.0, 'v3': -2.0, 'v5': -2.0, 'v2': -2....
4    {'v3': -2.0, 'v5': -2.0, 'v6': -2.0, 'v1': -2....
dtype: object
```

Comment: While this was very helpful, I also found that using `dropna()` later gave me a `KeyError` when I was iterating over this data structure. I found `fillna()` to be more useful in my case to avoid the `KeyError` by using `fillna('')` to test if the corresponding value existed or not. So, my full solution was: `df.apply(lambda x : x.fillna('').to_dict(),axis=1)`