# If dictionary array consists of "nan" then return no entry

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge

I have two table files as below.

main.txt:

```
Food    Total
fruit   1500
vegetable   0
meat    0
grain   600
fish    65
```

and sub.txt:

```
Food    Item    Count   Percent
fruit   apple   450 30
fruit   orange  300 20
fruit   banana  750 50
grain   rice    120 20
grain   maize   480 80
fish    salmon  65  100
```

I would like to merge `sub.txt` to `main.txt`, then convert it into dictionary in a column. So I ran the codes as below and generated the output :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> main = pd.read_csv("main.txt", sep="\t")
>>> sub = pd.read_csv("sub.txt", sep="\t")
>>> 
>>> out = (main.merge(sub, on='Food', how='left')
...         .groupby(['Food','Total'])['Item','Count','Percent']
...         .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records')))
>>> 
>>> out
Food       Total
fish       65       [{'Item': 'salmon', 'Count': 65.0, 'Percent': ...
fruit      1500     [{'Item': 'apple', 'Count': 450.0, 'Percent': ...
grain      600      [{'Item': 'rice', 'Count': 120.0, 'Percent': 2...
meat       0            [{'Item': nan, 'Count': nan, 'Percent': nan}]
vegetable  0            [{'Item': nan, 'Count': nan, 'Percent': nan}]
dtype: object
```

As you can see from the `out` object, `nan` was created when there is no information for `meat` and `vegetable` (because the `Total` is 0). I was trying to return empty entity for those with `nan`. So ideally for those with `nan`, I wish to have an output as below:

```
Food       Total
fish       65       [{'Item': 'salmon', 'Count': 65.0, 'Percent': ...
fruit      1500     [{'Item': 'apple', 'Count': 450.0, 'Percent': ...
grain      600      [{'Item': 'rice', 'Count': 120.0, 'Percent': 2...
meat       0            []
vegetable  0            []
dtype: object
```

But I have no clue how to remove the whole entity and return as empty for those with `nan`.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out from another post [python dataframe to_dict by index, exclude NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269844/python-dataframe-to-dict-by-index-exclude-nan). So I just need to add `dropna()` to the `apply` function.

```
.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(orient='records')))
```